# Erratic and inconsistent autocomplete in PHPStorm

Tags: php, autocomplete, ide, phpstorm

My PHPStorm v 7 is behaving very erratically and inconsistently when it comes to autocompetion.

For example, given a variable `$test_variable` which has been previously declared, if I attempt to quickly retype this variable by typing 'tes...', it sometimes does NOT auto suggest the variable `$test_variable` unless I include the dollar sign prefix (i.e. typing '$test...').

On other occasions, even if I don't include the dollar sign, it successfully suggests to autocomplete the variable.

Why is this? Why is it behaving so inconsistently? Same thing happens with declared functions. Sometimes it produces the correct suggestion but other times it does not. Is this a bug with PHPStorm?

Comment: In general all auto completion for PHP sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, since phpstorm7, it seems really odd. For example.

```
.test {
font-size: 10px !imp;
```

}

Then hitting tab with the cursor between the p and the semicolon will produce this mess:

```
.test {
font-size: 10px ! -webkit-animation-play-state : running;
-moz-animation-play-state: running;
-o-animation-play-state: running;
animation-play-state: running;;
```

}

Sorry I realise this is not an answer, but wanted to share your concern.
As for an answer, switch to PHPStorm 5. Seemed a lot more predictable.